# Azure WASABi + custom AppDomains = System.DllNotFoundException

Tags: azure, autoscaling

I have 2 workers and autoscaller (WASABi) in my app. Each worker computing some data in manually created AppDomains (`AppDomain.CreateDomain()` and so on). One domain is for one computing task.

Sometimes there are few task to complete. All works fine, no exception occurs.

But sometimes there are a lot of tasks to complete. In these moments autoscaller has to add one more worker (made with reactive rules). After new instance is loaded, magic happens: in custom AppDomain there is such exception:

```
State: Error System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment' threw an exception. --->
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'kernel32.dll': The filename or extension is too long. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700CE)
 at Microsoft.Win32.SafeNativeMethods.OutputDebugString(String message)
 at System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener.Write(String message, Boolean useLogFile)
 at System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.WriteHeader(String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id) at System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.TraceEvent(TraceEventCache eventCache, String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String format, Object[] args)
 at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, String format, Object[] args) at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment..cctor()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace
 --- at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.get_CurrentRoleInstance()
 at Tailspin.Shared.Infrastructure.Helpers.LogError(Exception ex, String message, Object[] args) at Tailsping.Workers.Processor.ChannelUpdater.Update()
 at Tailsping.Workers.Processor.AppdomainHelper.b__1[T]()
 at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
 at Tailsping.Workers.Processor.AppdomainHelper.RunInAppDomain[T](Func`1 func)
 at Tailsping.Workers.Processor.ProcessorService.ExecWrapperInternal(String wrapperXml)
```

It can not load some DLL called '**kernel32.dll**' :)

Google says noting. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any resolution to this? We're running into a similar problem.